# How to do a plot in r with two lines

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I have to do a graph with two datas, but all the codes that I have used is not going. Here's what is written on the statement of the question:

"Plot the average percentage agreement with the United States across all countries over time. Also, add the average percentage agreement with Russia as another line for comparison."

Here's the dataset: unvoting <- read.csv ("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/umbertomig/intro-prob-stat-FGV/master/datasets/unvoting.csv")

Here's what I have done so far:

```
data<- unvoting
    data<- data.frame(tapply(data$PctAgreeUS, data$CountryName, sum))

data<- unvoting
   data<- data.frame(tapply(data$PctAgreeRUSSIA, data$CountryName, sum))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a tidyverse solution:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

unvoting %>% 
  group_by(Year) %>% 
  summarise(Average_US = mean(PctAgreeUS), Average_RUS = mean(PctAgreeRUSSIA)) %>%
  na.omit() %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c(Average_US, Average_RUS)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Year, y = value, colour = name)) + 
  geom_line()
```

[image]